Is Typescript so restrictive with Array.includes() that it can never return false?
I have a typed array but typescript only lets me use the Array.includes() function with values that are included in the array, doesn't that mean it will never return false?
type Pet = 'cat' | 'dog' | 'fish' | 'hamster';
const pets: Pet[] = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'hamster'];

const someInput1: string = 'fish';
const someInput2: string = 'snake';

pets.includes('cat'); // true
pets.includes(someInput1); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pet'.ts(2345)
pets.includes(someInput2); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pet'.ts(2345)

I know that someInput2 could be a value that is not included in the array, thats the reason I am calling that function, because I want to know if someInput2 is included in the array or not
I have found a lot of ways to hide this error, like
(pets as string[]).includes(someInput2); // false
pets.includes(someInput2 as any); // false
pets.some((value) => value === someInput2) // false

const allPets: string[] = pets;
allPets.includes(someInput2); // false

But my question is not about how to work around this, but to know if this a typescript bug? if not, what is the indented way to use Array.includes()

You're declaring Pet type alias as an union of literals. That's different, to Typescript, of an  array of string. It's by design. Check here.

The whole point of using a literal type is so that this will raise an error.

see the answers to the questions linked above. It's not considered a bug, but essentially a missing TS feature... as per ms/TS#26255 and the issue it's considered a duplicate of, ms/TS#14520.  TS is expecting you to widen your array element type and check for those. Widening to string[] (or more safely to readonly string[]) is the way to check for arbitrary strings.  If ms/TS#14520 were implemented, presumably includes would use a lower bound constraint instead.

Are you trying to narrow someInput1/someInput2 to Pet (example)?
